# Unable to install httpd on my remote machine using Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a CentOS machine in AWS on which I intended to install **httpd** which requires us to be root. I am using `become_method : sudo` to work as root but still I could not solve it.

This is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts : aws
  connection : ssh
  remote_user : centos
  become_method : sudo
  gather_facts : yes
  tasks :
  - name : Connect to the remote host and executing yum updates
    yum : name=* state=latest
  - name : Installing HTTPD Server
    yum : name=httpd state=latest
  - name : Deploy the static website
    copy : src=../files/index.html dest=/var/www/html/index.html owner=centos group=centos mode=0655 backup=yes
  - name : Restart the HTTPD Service
    service: name=httpd state=restarted
  - name : Wait for the HTTPD port 80 to be listening
    wait_for : host=ec2-54-152-85-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com
  - name : Installing WGET to test the site
    yum : name=wget state=latest
  - name : Test the site
    shell : /usr/bin/wget http://localhost
    register : site_result
  - name : Display the site output results
    debug : var=site_result
```

By doing this, I encountered the following error:

```
TASK [Connect to the remote host and executing yum updates] ********************
task path: /home/centos/Playbooks/example/example_playbook.yaml:8
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/ansible/modules/core/packaging/os/yum.py
<ec2-54-152-85-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
<ec2-54-152-85-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -q -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/centos/AnsibleKeyPair.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=centos -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/centos/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r ec2-54-152-85-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'"'"''
fatal: [ec2-54-152-85-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com]: FAILED! => {
"changed": true,
"failed": true,
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "conf_file": null,
        "disable_gpg_check": false,
        "disablerepo": null,
        "enablerepo": null,
        "exclude": null,
        "install_repoquery": true,
        "list": null,
        "name": [
            "*"
        ],
        "state": "latest",
        "update_cache": false,
        "validate_certs": true
    },
    "module_name": "yum"
},
"msg": "You need to be root to perform this command.\n",
"rc": 1,
"results": [
    "Loaded plugins: fastestmirror\n"
]
}
```

Comment: Just a bit of feedback, your syntax is a bit odd and makes it harder to read. Generally in YAML you only use a space after a colon, not before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close enough, to let Ansible elevate to root you will need to add `become: yes` to your playbook.

```
- hosts: aws
  connection: ssh
  remote_user: centos
  become_method: sudo
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  [...]
```

Just as a note, you don't need to explicitly specify: `connection` `become_method` `gather_facts`, they will all default to those values.

**EDIT:**

By default CentOS comes out with `Default: requiretty`, so you have 2 ways of fixing it:

1. Comment out the line with `requiretty` in `sudoers` file
2. Disable `pipelining` adding `pipelinig: no` in your playbook

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `latest` use `present` or `installed`, as `state`, for installing `httpd`

```yaml
- yum: 
    name: httpd 
    state: installed
  become: yes
```

Or

```yaml
- yum: 
    name: httpd 
    state: present
  become: yes
```